# Irreducible Quartic equation.

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals, symmetric-functions

Consider the set of equations 
$$\tag{A}
x^{\frac 1 2}+y = 11
$$
$$\tag{B}
x +y^{\frac 1 2} = 7
$$
With mere inspection and guessing, the Solution Set is ${4,9}$ . However I cannot not find a method to solve them beyond that.

Let  $x^{\frac 1 2}=t $ . Then $x=t^2$ and $y=11-t$.

Inserting the value of x and y in terms of t into equation B yields
     $t^4-13t+38=0      ……(C)$

Is there a mistake and what should be the next step to arrive at the solution.
Equation $C$ is wrong as it has been pointed out.

Comment: Well, the second tells us that $y=(7-x)^2$ so you can get a quartic out of the first one.

Comment: Then we try $\pm2,\pm19$ for the rational roots of $(7-t^2)^2=11-t\Leftrightarrow t^4 - 14 t^2 + t + 38 = 0$ as any rational root, multiplied by $a_n$ should divide $a_0$

Comment: Your equation (C) is wrong because as you yourself observe t=2 should be a solution, but it isn't. When you derive the correct (C) then you can divide by t-2 and get an equation of degree 3.

Comment: Yes, we can get another quartic equation but then again it's also irreducible.

Comment: Yes. equation C is wrong, well that's a dead end.

Comment: We get $$(x-4) \left(x^3-24 x^2+176 x-361\right)=0$$

Comment: If you write $u=\sqrt{x}$ and $v=\sqrt{y}$, then the first equation gives a parabola symmetric about the $u$-axis, and the second equation gives a parabola symmetric about the $v$-axis.  The parabolas have four intersections.  Due to the nature of their axes of symmetry, there is exactly one intersection point in each quadrant.  Since $u=\sqrt{x}$ and $v=\sqrt{y}$, the solution we seek must be in the first quadrant, and from the above argument, there is only one such solution.  Since you have found $(u,v)=(2,3)$ (corresponding to $(x,y)=(4,9)$), it is the only solution.

Comment: @WEtutorialSchool , Is it the only solution that is real ?Since the number roots of the set of equations must be 4 for a quartic equation.

Comment: Including negative $u$ and $v$, there are $4$ solutions, all of which are real.  Only one solution satisfies $u,v\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$y^{1/2}=7-x$$ so $$y=(7-x)^2$$ and $$x^{1/2}=11-(7-x)^2$$ and $$x-(14x-x^2-38)^2=0$$ this is
$$- \left( x-4 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}-24\,{x}^{2}+176\,x-361 \right) =0$$ after expanding and factorizing.

Comment: the factorization process looks difficult